# When do we get Rejection Messages in Oracle SOA

Tags: oracle-soa

What all kind of errors result in Rejected Messages other than Translation errors? I have to desgin a fault policy for handling Rejected Messages, i need to be sure that only Translation errors get catched.

Answer (score 1):

All the inbound adapter translation errors lead to Rejected Messages. If your incoming data at runtime is not in compliance with the XSD defined at design time, then all such translation errors leads to Rejected Messages. As you mentioned, use a fault policy file to handle them.